# Cant Split and Store hexstring in array

Tags: c, strtol

i wanted to split this hexstring, convert em, and store em in an array.
but it seems there is something off from my work, and i don't know what.

I intend to split this string

> 27CA6B

to

```
 27
 CA
 6B
```

but the output is always only the first string.
like

```
27
51819
0
```

please somebody help, here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
 {
char bc[] = "27CA6B";
char *theEnd;

long result;
long resulta;
long resultb;
long resultc;

result = strtol (bc, &theEnd, 0);
resulta = strtol (theEnd, &theEnd, 16 );
resultb = strtol (theEnd, NULL, 0);

//int i = 0;
//printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", bc[0], bc[1], bc[2], bc[3], bc[4], bc[5]);

printf("%ld\n", result, &bc[0]);
printf("%ld\n", resulta, &bc[1]);
printf("%ld\n", resultb, &bc[2]);


return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Note: `CA6B` is valid as whole in hex.

Comment: yes, its a the whole CA6B in decimal, but i wanted it to be separated away like my intention

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? Your first paragraph makes it seem you want to split a string of 6 characters into 3 strings with two characters each, but your code looks like you have to convert a decimal number, followed by a hex number, followed by another decimal one. Are the lengths fixed? Are there no separators?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: the general purpose is i want to split a string with 6 characters into 3 string with 2 char each one, then i want to convert them to int using strtol and store em in array. no, no separator, nothing at all. if my code looks confusing, dont mind,, im just blankly try everything to do my goal because im new in c, thats why my code looks strange

Comment: @MichaelWalz thats my whole code

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Answer (score 1):

The "issue" that you see in because of this line

```
 resulta = strtol (theEnd, &theEnd, 16 );
```

there, `theEnd` points to `CA6B` which, as per the base 16, is a valid input as whole, so the whole string is consumed and converted. The decimal representation value is 51819, which you see as output.

The best way to achieve this would be (based on your approach) to take a pointer to the starting of the array, and "clip" it on alternate indexes.

That said, all your `printf()` statements are logically wrong, as you have only one format specifier but you supply two arguments, so as the last one will be ignored silently.

Comment: what should i do to make it separate hex value?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char bc[] = "27CA6B";
    unsigned char result[(sizeof(bc)-1)/2] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    for(char *p = bc; *p; p += 2){
        char part[3] = {0};
        memcpy(part, p, 2);//Extract 2 characters
        result[i++] = strtoul(part, NULL, 16);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(result); ++i){
        printf("%3u %c%c\n", result[i], bc[i*2], bc[i*2+1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

expand loop

```
unsigned char result1,result2,result3;
int i = 0;
char part[3] = {0};

memcpy(part, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
result1 = strtoul(part, NULL, 16);
memcpy(part, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
result2 = strtoul(part, NULL, 16);
memcpy(part, bc + i, 2); i += 2;
result3 = strtoul(part, NULL, 16);

i = 0;
printf("%3u %c%c\n", result1, bc[i], bc[i+1]); i += 2;
printf("%3u %c%c\n", result2, bc[i], bc[i+1]); i += 2;
printf("%3u %c%c\n", result3, bc[i], bc[i+1]); i += 2;
```

Comment: i need the value to be stored in variable so i can do something with it

Comment: @user6318361 It is better to use arrays than to use separate variables. (However, loops can be expanded.)

Comment: thank god.. its perfect.. thank you so much, you save a lot of time for me, thanks blue